# to look good vs to look well

Tags: adjectives

She likes to look **well** should be transferred into She likes to look **good**. How to explain this to my students?

Comment: Explain to your students that English idiomatic usage dictates that "look good" and "look bad" are pairs meaning to appear pleasing and not pleasing (respectively), while "look well" and "look ill" are pairs meaning to appear healthy and appear sick (respectively).

Answer (score 1):

An answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/47822) on the EnglishStackExchange answers it very well:

> If you write, "Sally looks good in her new dress", "good" is an
>   adjective. The construction is similar to if you wrote, "The dress
>   looks blue".
>
> If you write, "Sally looks well", people would normally understand you
>   to mean "well" in the sense of healthy. Again, "well" is an adjective.

Therefore, *she likes to look well* would imply that she liles to look healthy. On the other hand, *she likes to look good* implies that she likes to look attractive/good in appearance.